# Subclassing Slick.Grid

Tags: design-patterns, inheritance, decorator, slickgrid

I'm new to SlickGrid, and very happy with it so far.
But today I came across one situation I'm not sure how to solve.

I'd like to add some extra HTML markup to every row, a part from the , but I didn't find any way of decorating that HTML, so I was thinking of extending Slick.Grid to override "appendRowHtml" method.

What inheritance technique would you suggest to do so? Or would you suggest another approach...

thanks in advance,

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  There are hooks to apply custom formatting to cells in a column (formatter) and to add a function that can add a css class to rows (rowCssClasses).  Can you provide a bit more information on exactly what you need to do?

Comment: sure, in this case, I'm looking to display extra information for a row in context, opening a panel after it. Like adding content between rows in this case... But I'm also interested in the broader picture, on how to subclass SlickGrid in case I would like to override any other method.

Comment: @Marc Did you ever find a "nice", clean way of doing this (i.e. subclassing/extending slickgrid's main grid definition)?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply redefine the function instead of trying to "subclass" a javascript object. For instance:

```
Slick.Grid.appendRowHtml = function(...){
    ...
}
```

To be safe, you should copy over the old function and then work on that, to make sure your function accepts the same parameters and returns similar things. This way you can easily prevent SlickGrid from crashing.

Good luck :)

Comment: the problem is that this appendRowHtml is kind of a inner/private method defined in an anonymous function context that is not accessible from outside, so I don't think it can be redefined so easily

Comment: You "don't think" or did you try and it didn't work? I'm not 100% sure if it works either, but you could give it a shot before dismissing it i guess...